# How can I keep the error message in a custom dialog from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, angular, rxjs

Thank you in advance.

I have a modal dialog that, under certain conditions, features an error message.  When the error message is displayed, the error text always renders below the error icon.  I need to get them to display on the same line.

I've tried adding styling to widen the form-error-message element, but it does not affect the wrapping.

This is all contained in a 'custom-modal' dialog directive (that I don't control).  But, I need to adjust the formatting regardless.

Please help.

HTML

```
<custom-modal id="checkbox-modal">
    <ng-container container-label>
        <div class="form-error-message" *ngIf="inErrorCondition">
            <custom-icon>error</custom-icon><h3>Error message here!</h3>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</custom-modal>
```

The 'form-error-message' class has the following attributes:

```
height: 2rem;
border: solid 1px;
padding: 1.5rem
font-weight: 700;
```

CSS

```
.custom-modal {
    top: 30%
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom-modal {
    top: 30%
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.form-error-message {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1.5rem
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<custom-modal id="checkbox-modal">
    <ng-container container-label>
        <div class="form-error-message" *ngIf="inErrorCondition">
            <custom-icon>error</custom-icon><h3>Error message here!</h3>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</custom-modal>
```

Is this what you're looking for? If so, it's because the height you set for the div wasn't large enough to have the error message text displayed within the div.

Or...do you need the height of the div to remain as 2rem and have the "error" displayed at the left of the div and maybe have the "Error message here!" displayed in the centre of the div?

Comment: Nathan - thanks for the response.

To be clear 'error' is the icon type (a triangle with an exclamation point).  My goal is to get the icon and the text to appear next to one another on the same line.  

If it would work, I'm open to widening the dialog or adjusting the padding, font-weight, etc..  Or, apply any other formatting that won't materially change the appearance.  The font, border and color have to remain.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the height did not cause it to 'unwrap'.

Comment: FYI - 'custom-modal' also has the following attributes:


'code'
width: 31.25rem;
vertical-align: top;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
z-index: 1000;
text-align: left;
'code'


'text-align' will change the position of the icon/text, but not 'unwrap' it.